# Select an option in a select box, given the option in word form in a PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms, selection, drop-down-menu

I have a standard **select** box in my php form for my website containing a list of counties in the UK, an example of which is shown below:

```
<p class='form_title'>County<br>
    <select id="county" name="county">
        <optgroup label="England">
            <option>Bedfordshire</option>
            <option>Berkshire</option>
            <option>Bristol</option>

            ....

            <option>Wiltshire</option>
            <option>Worcestershire</option>
        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="Wales">
            <option>Anglesey</option>

            ...

            <option>Radnorshire</option>
        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="Scotland">
            <option>Aberdeenshire</option>

            ...

            <option>Wigtownshire</option>
        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="Northern Ireland">
            <option>Antrim</option>

            ...

            <option>Tyrone</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</p>
```

Once a user has submitted details, they can then edit them.

I therefore need a way to have selected the option that they previously chose, given that I have the option they chose saved in word form, such as **Bedfordshire**.

I know I need to add the word **selected** to one of the options, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it than a massive **case** statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set an option value for each option to track the value.

Also you should be generating that from a database and then you can set `selected` based on a `$_GET` or `$_POST`:

for example:

```
foreach($county as $name){
    $selected = '';
    if($name == $_GET['name']){
        $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$name.'"'.$selected.'>'.$name.'</option>';
}
```

this doesn't include your `optgroup` but that also should come from database.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
  foreach($places as $place) {
      $selected = $prevSelectionId == $place['id'] ? " selected='selected' " : "";
      echo "<option $selected value='".$place['id']."'>".$place['name']."</option>";
  }
 </select>
```